# Getting 503: 'Service Unavailable' when using Amadeus Airport Search autocomplete API

Tags: python, amadeus

Why am I getting 503 Service unavailable ?

I am listing my request response made through python and log enabled

```
def origin_airport_search(request):    
    try:
        data = []
        data = amadeus.reference_data.locations.get(keyword=request.GET.get('term', None), subType=Location.ANY).data
    except ResponseError as error:
        messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, error)
    response = HttpResponse(get_city_airport_list(data), 'application/json')
    response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    return response

def get_city_airport_list(data):
    result = []
    for i, val in enumerate(data):
        result.append(data[i]['iataCode']+', '+data[i]['name'])
    result = list(dict.fromkeys(result))
    return json.dumps(result)
```

```
Request
{'app_id': None,
 'app_version': None,
 'bearer_token': 'Bearer j3LmvpBQAKf4ANo16LZlDA6H0IDd',
 'client_version': '5.0.0',
 'headers': {'Accept': 'application/json, application/vnd.amadeus+json',
             'Authorization': 'Bearer j3LmvpBQAKf4ANo16LZlDA6H0IDd',
             'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.amadeus+json',
             'User-Agent': 'amadeus-python/5.0.0 python/3.7.9'},
 'host': 'test.api.amadeus.com',
 'http_request': <urllib.request.Request object at 0x000001CBDDC54488>,
 'language_version': '3.7.9',
 'params': {'keyword': 'kol', 'subType': 'AIRPORT,CITY'},
 'path': '/v1/reference-data/locations',
 'port': 443,
 'scheme': 'https',
 'ssl': True,
 'url': 'https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/reference-data/locations?keyword=kol&subType=AIRPORT%2CCITY',
 'verb': 'GET'}
```

```
Response
{'body': '{"errors":[{"status":503,"code":19,"title":"No available service for '
         'processing the request.","source":{"pointer":"uri"}}]}',
 'data': None,
 'headers': <http.client.HTTPMessage object at 0x000001CBDDD35C88>,
 'http_response': <HTTPError 503: 'Service Unavailable'>,
 'parsed': True,
 'request': <amadeus.client.request.Request object at 0x000001CBDD8BD988>,
 'result': {'errors': [{'code': 19,
                        'source': {'pointer': 'uri'},
                        'status': 503,
                        'title': 'No available service for processing the '
                                 'request.'}]},
 'status_code': 503}
```

EDIT: Its working on Windows now may be amadeus had some sever error in test environment. Thanks to Anthony for mentioning this out.

I need another help with - When I am running the same code in MAC, its giving me this ssl error response.

```
Request
{'app_id': None,
 'app_version': None,
 'bearer_token': None,
 'client_version': '5.0.0',
 'headers': {'Accept': 'application/json, application/vnd.amadeus+json',
             'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
             'User-Agent': 'amadeus-python/5.0.0 python/3.9.2'},
 'host': 'test.api.amadeus.com',
 'http_request': <urllib.request.Request object at 0x109523fd0>,
 'language_version': '3.9.2',
 'params': {'client_id': 'client-key',
            'client_secret': 'client-secret',
            'grant_type': 'client_credentials'},
 'path': '/v1/security/oauth2/token',
 'port': 443,
 'scheme': 'https',
 'ssl': True,
 'url': 'https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token',
 'verb': 'POST'}
Response
{'body': None,
 'data': None,
 'headers': {},
 'http_response': URLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1123)')),
 'parsed': False,
 'request': <amadeus.client.request.Request object at 0x109523e50>,
 'result': None,
 'status_code': None}
```

Comment: May be their servers went down? Check the API status with Amadeus support.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, The Airport & City Search API had an issue in the test environment. Everything should be fixed now, can you try your code again and let us know if it works for you.